# How to change the name of Spark application after it is started?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am having trouble updating/reconfiguring a predefined Spark Context called "spark"

```
spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.app.name")
```

Returns the app name 'Databricks Shell' I want to update this and I try using:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.app.name', 'New_Name')
```

However this does not update anything, because when I again run

```
spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.app.name")
```

I still get 'Databricks Shell' How do I update or make any changes to the spark context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** You cannot change the name of a Spark application after it's up and running.

---

It is simply too late as other services could rely on the value and initialize themselves appropriately (e.g. web UI).

You could expect that such a change would be propagated to other Spark services but that's not the case.

That's why you define the application name and the master URL while starting a Spark application. It's a prerequisite to have the two values set upon startup.

---

Please note that `spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.app.name")` is a hack and you should really be using `spark.sparkContext.appName` instead.

Please also note that the types of the objects you work with for configuration are different and they really are for two different modules - Spark Core (`SparkContext`) and Spark SQL (`SparkSession.conf`).

And in the recent versions of Spark, `_conf` is no longer accessible.

```
scala> spark.version
res2: String = 2.4.4

scala> spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.app.name")
<console>:24: error: variable _conf in class SparkContext cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.SparkContext
       spark.sparkContext._conf.get("spark.app.name")
                          ^
```

You should actually be using `spark.sparkContext.getConf` instead.

Again the two configuration objects are different.

```
scala> :type spark.sparkContext.getConf
org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala> :type spark.conf
org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify config and application name with SparkConf or on SparkSession builder

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

# with SparkConf()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('TA').set("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('TA').set("spark.executor.memory", "12g")
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

#with SparkSession builder
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I had customized configs for the SparkSession "spark" before this would they be lost?

Comment: there is no restriction to create SparkSession instances, can be created as needed and can be multiple instances with various config options

Comment: After running the code you sent I still get: ('spark.app.name', 'Databricks Shell') and I am unsure why. Even if I name the session spark2 it is still named Databricks Shell