# Spark session properties which can be be set/modified after Databricks cluster is running

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I was going through this [change the name of Spark application after it is started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138669/how-to-change-the-name-of-spark-application-after-it-is-started). I had a doubt that which all properties are there which we can change through spark session after application is started.

For example there are some properties mentioned below which can be set in notebook after application is started while we need to write to Datalake.

```py
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", clientId) 
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential",secretId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse , these authentication config also can be set after the cluster started  With Spark configs, the Azure Data Lake Store settings can be specified per notebook. However, This method strongly discourage you from storing secrets in plaintext. You can ref : [link](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/data-import/azure-data-lake-store.html)